# Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net, deserialization

Here is the code:

```
        string s = "2012-08-08T01:54:45.3042880+00:00";

        JObject j1 = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            time=s
        });

        Object o = j1["time"];
```

We can check that o is string and equals "2012-08-08T01:54:45.3042880+00:00"

Now we transfer j1.ToString() to another program, which is

```
       {
          "time": "2012-08-08T01:54:45.3042880+00:00"
       }
```

then at the other program, try to parse it back to JObject, which is

```
       JObject j2 = JObject.Parse(j1.ToString());

       Object o2 = j2["time"];
```

Now, if we check o2, o2's type is Date, o2.ToString() is 8/7/2012 9:54:45 PM.

My question is:

**Is there is way to disable the Date deserialization for JObject.Parse , and just get the raw string?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 103, accepted):

When parsing from an `object` to `JObject` you can specify a `JsonSerializer` which instructs how to handle dates.

```
JObject.FromObject(new { time = s },
                   new JsonSerializer {
                          DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
                   });
```

Unfortunately `Parse` doesn't have this option, although it would make sense to have it.  Looking at the source for `Parse` we can see that all it does is instantiate a `JsonReader` and then passes that to `Load`.  `JsonReader` does have parsing options.

You can achieve your desired result like this:

```
  using(JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(j1.ToString()))) {
    reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
    JObject o = JObject.Load(reader);
  }
```

For background, see [Json.NET interprets and modifies ISO dates when deserializing to JObject #862](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862), specifically [this comment from JamesNK](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862#issuecomment-237539075): *I have no plans to change it, and I would do it again if give the chance.*

Comment: the program receive the whole json string which is {"time": "2012-08-08T01:54:45.3042880+00:00"},  so the program can not use JObject.FromObject to parse, has to use JObject.Parse to parse the string  and JOjbect.Parse only take 1 parameter.

Comment: @liuhongbo, weird that `Parse` doesn't provide the options that `FromObject` does.  This peaked my curiosity so I downloaded the source and found a solution.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thanks,Samuel Neff, that works perfect.
Also, found another way to handle this issue:

      JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings(); ;
      settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
      JObject j2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(j1.ToString(), settings);

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! Stopped me from implementing JsonReader.ToString and parsing the whole thing manually.

Comment: @Dav, glad it helped.  This was a fun one to figure out.

Comment: THANK YOU! I'd spent a few hours figuring out my own workaround, only to find that in one of our environments, JObject.Parse treats dates as day/month/year instead of month/day/year, which broke everything in a hurry. You're a lifesaver.

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks.
Just a minor note: The readers are disposable, so the correct code should be:

using var sr = new StringReader(j1.ToString());
using var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
var o = JObject.Load(reader);

Comment: By default, JsonTextReader closes its wrapped text reader when it is disposed, so it shouldn't necessary to dispose the StringReader.

To accurately replicate the behaviour of `JObject.Parse`, though, you should add `while(reader.Reader()) {}`. Otherwise, this will report success parsing a string that has content after the closing brace.

Comment: (see https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs)

Answer (score 22):

You can accomplish this using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` as well, by using `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
string s = "2012-08-08T01:54:45.3042880+00:00";
string jsonStr = $@"{{""time"":""{s}""}}";

JObject j1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonStr, new JsonSerializerSettings {DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None});
```

Comment: And for, say, `JArray`, use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonStr, new JsonSerializerSettings {DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None});`