# How to return unparsed string instead of DateTime from JProperty

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net

In MediaWiki's old query-continue style, it passes you a bunch of values that you're supposed to reflect back to MediaWiki unaltered. For example:

```
"query-continue": {
    "deletedrevs": {
        "drstart": "2014-09-06T20:14:15Z"
    }
}
```

How do I get the value as the exact string that was sent rather than a `DateTime` value? Asking for `(string)prop.Value` converts the object to a `DateTime` first and only then to a string, which results in returning the wrong date format.

The only thing I'm coming up with right now is checking to see if the value of the `JProperty` is a date, then converting the date back into ISO 8601, but considering that's how it was sent in the first place, that seems rather kludgy.

Comment: Are you deserializing into a C# class?

Comment: A C# Dictionary<string, string>, if you want to get technical, but yes.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11856694/497356) a duplicate?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find. Thanks!