# JToken: Get raw/original JSON value

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Is there a way to get the raw/original JSON value from a `JToken`?

The problem:

```
var data = JObject.Parse(@"{
    ""SimpleDate"":""2012-05-18T00:00:00Z"",
    ""PatternDate"":""2012-11-07T00:00:00Z""
}");

var value = data["SimpleDate"].Value<string>();
```

The `value` is now `05/18/2012 00:00:00` but I need the original string `2012-05-18T00:00:00Z`.

Is there a way to get this original value? Also, I cannot change the way how the `JObject` is created (e.g. change settings), because it is passed as parameter into my class...

(Reference: [The original NJsonSchema issue](https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/issues/22))

Comment: I have a similar problem trying to parse an extended DateTime format (containing millesconds).

To make the original question more clear: What if I have a free-text field like for a comment and the user enters something looking like a ISO DateTime? Would it be impossible to parse this string as is?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot get the original string, date strings are recognized and converted to `DateTime` structs inside the [`JsonReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) itself.  You can see this if you do:

```
Console.WriteLine(((JValue)data["SimpleDate"]).Value.GetType()); // Prints System.DateTime
```

You can, however, extract the dates in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by doing:

```
var value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data["SimpleDate"]);
// value is "2012-05-18T00:00:00Z"
```

This will always output a `JValue` in a JSON-appropriate string format.  Since your original dates are in this format, this may meet your needs.

(Honestly, I'm surprised [`JValue.ToString()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_ToString.htm) outputs dates in non-ISO format, given that [`JObject.ToString()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString.htm) does output contained dates in ISO format.)

If you were able to change you settings while reading your `JObject`, you could use [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm) to disable `DateTime` recognition:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(@"{
    ""SimpleDate"":""2012-05-18T00:00:00Z"",
    ""PatternDate"":""2012-11-07T00:00:00Z""
}", settings);

var value = data["SimpleDate"].Value<string>();

Debug.WriteLine(value); // Outputs 2012-05-18T00:00:00Z
```

There's no overload to [`JObject.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) that takes a `JsonSerializerSettings`, so use [`DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_2.htm).  This setting eventually gets propagated to [`JsonReader.DateParseHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_DateParseHandling.htm).

Related Newtonsoft docs:

- [Json.NET interprets and modifies ISO dates when deserializing to JObject #862](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862#issuecomment-222850780)
- [Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm).

Comment: That's bad: I'm working on a JSON Schema validator, which takes a JObject and may validate such a date string with a regex pattern. This no longer matches when the value is converted into a DateTime...

Comment: Maybe a bit of [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here?  Could you leverage the fact that Json.NET has already recognized and parsed the date in your validator?  There's no standard for dates in JSON after all, see http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm.

Comment: It seems that the only option is to disable date parsing when creating the JObject... here the original problem: https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/issues/22

Comment: Its not an xy prob :-), i'm trying to implement a JSON Schema validator which takes a JObject. The JSON Schema may require more than only a date-time format for a property and may fail because of this automatic transformation...

Comment: @RicoSuter - In that case I restored part of my original answer, in case it's useful.

Answer (score 7):

There's a solution I found in [Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856694/json-net-disable-the-deserialization-on-datetime):

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(j1.ToString()));
reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
JObject o = JObject.Load(reader);
```

Comment: * Remember that JsonReader implements IDisposable!

Answer (score -4):

another approach - that would work - Regex

```
SimpleDate(?:.*):(?:.*?)\"([0-9|-]{1,}T[0-9|:]+Z)
```

it is a regex pattern to extract the data you look for - you just wanted the string, so here it is .
it is not the JSON parsing approach - but it indeed extracts the string.

[here is a sample of how it works](https://regex101.com/r/vD8kP1/1)

Comment: it is an answer - the question was to extract the "string" not how to fine tune the Json parse