# JSON.NET: Get Specific JSON Date Value

Tags: json, regex, vb.net, date, json.net

In my VB.NET project, using JSON.NET, I've got a JSON from a Web API that has a value representing a date in the `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` format, and I'd like to simply get that value.

Here's more or less what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    "REQ_DATE": "2016-01-17T12:27:57",
    "REQ_TYPE": "Vacation",
    "HOURS": 500.0,
    "LEAVE_TIME": "8:00 AM",
    "LEAVE_DATE": "2016-01-23T00:00:00",
    "DUE_TIME": "8:00 AM",
    "DUE_DATE": "2016-01-24T00:00:00",
}
```

So I should just serialize it and do what I will with the value, right? However, when I put that key-value in a variable, the date format is automatically changed!

```
Dim temp As String = myJsonResult("REQ_DATE")
' temp = "1/17/2016 12:27:57 PM"
```

I need to have that Date as it was from the retrieved JSON. I see two ways to go about this problem: converting it to `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` manually, or using regex to directly grab the key-value pair - both of which I have had no success with.

My attempt to convert it into DateTime:

```
Dim tempDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myJsonResult("REQ_DATE").ToString,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
' Error: String is not Recognized as valid DateTime
Dim myDesiredResult As String = tempDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
```

My attempt to use Regex:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("""REQ_DATE"": ""([\d\w]*)""")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match(myJsonAsString)
If match.Success Then
   Dim myDesiredResult As String = match.Groups(1).Value
End If
' match is empty...
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `myJsonResult` is a `JObject` into which you have loaded your JSON.

Your difficulty is that Json.NET automatically recognizes strings as dates when reading and converts them to `DateTime` structs.  Then when you later do `ToString()` on the value token, it comes back in c#'s "invariant culture" format rather than the original format, which in this case was [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  If you do not want this behavior, you can parse your JSON using [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm):

```
        Dim jsonString = "{'REQ_DATE':'2016-01-17T12:27:57','REQ_TYPE':'Vacation','HOURS':500.0,'LEAVE_TIME':'8:00 AM','LEAVE_DATE':'2016-01-23T00:00:00','DUE_TIME':'8:00 AM','DUE_DATE':'2016-01-24T00:00:00'}"
        Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings() With { _
            .DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None _
        }
        Dim myJsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(jsonString, settings)
        Dim dateValue = myJsonResult("REQ_DATE")
        Dim dateString = CType(dateValue, String) 'Value is 2016-01-17T12:27:57
```

There's no overload to [`JObject.Parse()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) that takes a `JsonSerializerSettings`, so you would need to use [`DeserializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_2.htm).  This setting eventually gets propagated to [`JsonReader.DateParseHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_DateParseHandling.htm).

Alternatively, if you are OK with Json.NET recognizing dates but would always like them to be printed in ISO 8601 format, you can re-serialize the token to JSON rather than just getting the string value:

```
        Dim dateValue = myJsonResult("REQ_DATE")
        Dim dateString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dateValue).Trim(""""c) 'Value is 2016-01-17T12:27:57
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZoPC5x).  Related [c# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138346/jtoken-get-raw-original-json-value/35141787).

Comment: Interesting. I've managed to make this work with my answer below, but this explains the automatic conversion - and the solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the parsed date-string from JSON.NET it will be in your culture's format as shown in your code comment:

```
Dim temp As String = myJsonResult("REQ_DATE")
' temp = "1/17/2016 12:27:57 PM"
```

That format is "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" so use that format for parsing.  But since it is in a format for your culture, you can let DateTime check/use *all* the known formats using `TryParse`:

```
Dim dt As DateTime
Dim temp As String = jobj("REQ_DATE").ToString

If DateTime.TryParse(temp, dt) Then
    'dt is good to use!
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString)
    ' Prints: 1/17/2016 12:27:57 PM
End If

Dim myDesiredResult As String = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
' result: "2016-01-17T12:27:57"
```

If you want to specify the format (it would be better to use `TryParseExact`):

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString())
' Also prints: 1/17/2016 12:27:57 PM
```

Dates dont have a format, so it cant change, but it may display differently for your culture settings.  You can display it any way you want, it is still the same date:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("HH yyyy MM mm dd"))
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"))
```

Comment: Thanks - based on your answer, I've got it to work. Specifically, see my answer below. I used `DateTime.Parse` instead

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I've got it to work simply by doing `DateTime.Parse` on the JObject, then doing `ToString` to my desired format.

```
    Dim temp As String = myRequest("REQ_DATE").ToString
    Dim tempDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(temp.ToString)
    Dim myDesiredResult As String = tempDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
```

I used dbc's answer in my code as it is more elegant.