# Converting JSON into class changes string value. Bug in JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json, string, json.net

I have a strange problem. I am using the JSON Framework from newtonsoft. But it is changing the date formatting of some of my strings.

I transfer some strings within a JSON string like this:

```
{"MyStrings":["Hello","World"]}
```

I have this matching DTO class:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<string> MyStrings { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to deserialize it into my DTO class like this:

```
string content = @"{""MyStrings"":[""2016-10-07T13:37:01.4209934Z"",""2016-10-07T13:37:01.4209934Z""]}";
var obj = JObject.Parse(content);
var test = obj.ToObject<Test>();
```

You see, in the JSON string there are strings that coincidentally look like a datetime value.

```
{
  "MyStrings":
    ["2016-10-07T13:37:01.4209934Z",
    "2016-10-07T13:37:01.4209934Z"]
}
```

If we investigate the string values, we get: `"10/07/2016 13:37:01"`.
Something completely different.

What is going on here? I did not change the default behavior. JSON.NET is changing the string values on his own. Why is this framework changing my string values? I want to leave it as it is - a string.

is this a bug in JSON.NET, or can I control this behavior with a special setting?

I tried all enum settings in the JsonSerializerSettings.

```
-DateParseHandling.None
-DateFormatString
-DateFormatHandling
-DateTimeZoneHandling
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: It looks like the library is parsing the contents of your JSON list as a list of DateTimes and then calling the `.ToString` method over them. Quite weird it looks like it's doing some extra unwanted work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11856694/10263)

Comment: @BrianRogers - Also related: [JToken: Get raw/original JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138346) and [JSON.NET: Get Specific JSON Date Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166060).  Given that this keeps coming up, I'm leaning towards thinking that the fact that `((JValue)DateTime.Now).ToString()` outputs in current culture format rather than invariant ISO 8601 format is a bug.

Comment: @dbc No argument from me-- it does seem very odd that JValue.ToString() outputs dates in a different format than JObject.ToString() does.

Comment: I've been running into this and have found an alternative to JSON.NET that doesn't have these DateTime issues, as it doesn't attempt to represent DateTimes within it's models https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's because you're using the standard JObject.Parse, which 'thinks' that these values are dates (and then call a ToString() on them when you do the .ToObject()).

Try this:

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(content);
```

Doing this,  the deserializer will know which is the target type of every property, I guess.

JsonConvert is a static class inside Newtonsoft.Json .

Comment: I cant directly use DeserializeObject<>. We use JSON.NET in a large engine and first it will be parsed. Later it will be converted into Type 'X'. So I have to split this. But I found a solution for the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I found "2021-03-11T00:00:00.0" to be changed into "2021-03-11T00:00:00" because of this (check .0 at the end). As I needed to bounce the received message to the caller, it lead to all kinds of integration issues.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my problem. Thanks to qwertoyo for his answer.

I cant directly use DeserializeObject<>. We use JSON.NET in a large engine and first it will be parsed. Later it will be converted into type 'X'.
So I have to split this.

This is working for my szenario:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
            };
object dto = jObject.ToObject(dtoType, JsonSerializer.Create(settings));
```

This is like the default-implementation for "JObject.ToObject" but you set your own JsonSerializerSettings.

Comment: Man this answer was a life-saver, thank you. We have experienced the behaviour when values were parsed into the controller properties and re-formatted by default. I think the `DateParseHandling.None` should be the default option and not this obscure behavior. I'm fine with formatting when parsing json->DateTime but not json->string.