# Json.NET interprets and modifies ISO dates when deserializing to JObject

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, json.net

I have a question connected with json deserilizing (Newtonsoft.Json). I don't understand the process deserialization `DateTime` types and date time formatted string, in other words type string, where it is written date like this "01.01.2000" and in `JObject` this field is string.

For example:

```
[
    {
        "DateOfBirth": "10.02.1990",
        "SomeString": "01.12.1888"
    }
]
```

I use the next deserialization setting:

```cs
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
       ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
       MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
       DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
       DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
       DateFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy",
       Converters = new List<JsonConverter>()
       {
          new StringEnumConverter(),
          new IsoDateTimeConverter
          {
             DateTimeFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
          }
       },
       Error = (sender, args) =>
       {
          args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
       },
    }
```

By default I expected that the first field is deserialize to `DateTime` 10/02/1990 00:00:00 and the second field deserialized to simple string in some object. But this is not so. Both field convert to `DateTime` format.
If I set `DateParseHandling.None` without `IsoDateTimeConverter` the result will be next: `DateTime` deserialize to null value and string will have "01.12.1888". But if I set both of this setting, everything OK.

Can someone explain this situation? And what should I do in order to get correct result without set random settings and hope for luck?

Comment: why would you expect "SomeString" to be deserialized to a string?  It looks like a valid date to me.

Comment: Can please [edit] your question to include a full [mcve] that reproduces the problem?  You show the settings but not how you are using them.   Your problem might be related to [JToken: Get raw/original JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141787/3744182), [Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11856694/3744182), or [JSON.NET: Get Specific JSON Date Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35166060/3744182), but I can't say for sure without seeing your complete code.

Comment: Also take a look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm.  What you are seeing might not be a bug.