# Deserialize a value serialized in two different ways with Json.Net

Tags: serialization, asp.net-core, json.net, deserialization

I have a class similar to this one:

```
public class Values
{
    public int BestValue { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllValues { get; set; }
}
```

This class could be (because of history) be stored either as

```
"MyFirstValue"  /* if only one value */
```

or

```
{ "BestValue" : 0, "AllValues" : ["DefaultValue", "OtherValue"] }
```

How can I deserialize this automatically using a `JsonConverter`? (Or any other solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for this purpose:

```
internal class ValuesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Values).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var tokenType = reader.SkipComments().TokenType;
        if (tokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var value = existingValue as Values ?? (Values)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
        if (tokenType == JsonToken.Date)
        {
            // Avoid annoying bug that converts date strings to local format described in 
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166060/json-net-get-specific-json-date-value
            value.AllValues = new List<string> { JToken.Load(reader).ToString(Formatting.None).Trim('"') };
        }
        else if (tokenType.IsPrimitive())
        {
            value.AllValues = new List<string> { (string)JToken.Load(reader) };
        }
        else
        {
            serializer.Populate(reader, value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader SkipComments(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }

    public static bool IsPrimitive(this JsonToken tokenType)
    {
        switch (tokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            case JsonToken.Float:
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
            case JsonToken.Undefined:
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.Date:
            case JsonToken.Bytes:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Then apply it to your type as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ValuesConverter))]
public class Values
{
    public int BestValue { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllValues { get; set; }
}
```

Or, add it to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) then modify your settings as shown in *[JsonSerializerSettings and Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35772387/3744182)*.

Notes -

- By setting [`CanWrite`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanWrite.htm) to false one can use default serialization when writing to JSON.
- When the JSON value is not a string, [`JsonSerializer.Populate()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm) is used to fill in the contents of `Values` via default deserialization.
- By using [`ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_DefaultCreator.htm) to construct the `Values` object, deserialization of subclasses of `Values` (if any) can be supported.

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ion3aX).

Comment: Thanks! Actually I already started to implement the converter, but I was missing the code inside the "read" method. The documentation on how to implement is actually not really clear... The `Populate` method is mostly what I was missing!
I was also missing the registration part, I thought the attribute was sufficient to register it.

Comment: Hum miread, the attribute is sufficient :D I saw several times these registrations not using attribute and I don't like them much.