# How to get raw datetime value from request body in Azure API Management?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management

Currently I'm trying to access the raw value of a JSON property in Azure API Management.
I have request as follows:

```
{
   "date": "2019-12-09T12:00:00Z"
}
```

and an operation like:

```xml
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- Assume datetime in format 2019-12-09T12:00:00Z -->
        <set-variable name="time" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<JObject>()["date"])" /> 
        <!-- Attempt to acquire raw value -->
        <set-variable name="rawValue" value="@{
            var value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((JValue)context.Variables["date"]);
            return value.ToString();
        }" />
        <!-- raw value is: \"2019-12-09T12:00:00Z\" -->
    </inbound>
```

I found a similar answer here:
[JToken: Get raw/original JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138346/jtoken-get-raw-original-json-value)
so I tried to serialize the object.

But in my case, Azure API Management outputs the raw value with additional quotes like this:

```
set-variable (0 ms)
{
    "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
    "name": "rawValue",
    "value": "\"2019-12-09T12:00:01Z\""
}
```

A simple way would be to replace them, but isn't there a better solution?

+++ UPDATE +++

Just found this solution:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.Body.As<JObject>()["date"]).ToString("o")
```

which outputs:

```
set-variable (0 ms)
{
    "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
    "expression": "Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.Body.As<JObject>()[\"date\"]).ToString(\"o\")",
    "value": "2019-12-10T09:10:00.0000000Z"
}
```

IMO this is still not 100% what I expected, but at least it's the right format.
I'm still open for any better solutions.

Comment: The raw value is `"2019-12-09T12:00:00Z"` because it's a string, so when you serialize it it becomes `"\"2019-12-09T12:00:00Z\""` because it's including the quotes.  Leave it as a date instead of serializing it.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually need to make sure, that the input format is exactly as stated above. Therefore, I regex check the value and this is only possible with a string. When using .ToString() method, the format is being overwritten by the default datetime format. Also the .ToString("o") and the ToString("u") are not quite the same format, so I've tried the JsonConvert method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the upcoming Azure API Management release announced [here](https://github.com/Azure/API-Management/releases/tag/release-service-2020-10), it should be possible to specify his own *JsonSerializerSettings* and could store the variable like this:

```
<set-variable name="body" value="@(context.Request.Body.AsJObject(preserveContent = true, new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None } ))" />
```

I'll post an update as soon as it's deployed and I could manage to test it.

#### Update

Using the new `context.Request.Body.AsJObject()` method in combination with the `JsonSerializer` settings, the output of the DateTime value now won't get changed anymore:

```json
{
    "source": "set-variable",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19T07:33:34.7901180Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:00.0018103",
    "data": {
        "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
        "name": "timestampFilter",
        "value": "2019-12-09T12:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're completely mixing up types here. `context.Request.Body.As<JObject>()["date"]` returns JToken that contains string value of `2019-12-09T12:00:00Z`. When you call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject((JValue)context.Variables["date"])` you ask JSON.NET to serialize given token into a string. Strings are represented in JSON as quoted series of characters, so of course `value` becomes equal to `"2019-12-09T12:00:01Z"`, i.e. string with `"` inside. If you want just the string value do:

```
<set-variable name="rawValue" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<JObject>()["date"].ToString())" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think this might be the first thing I've tried. As I said, whenever calling .ToString() this outputs me a different format:

set-variable (0 ms)
{
    "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
    "name": "rawValue",
    "value": "12/10/2019 9:10:00 AM"
}