# .Net Core Snapshot unit testing - Verify does not serialize Newtonsoft.Json JObject

Tags: .net-core, verify, snapshot-testing

I try to use [Verify](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/) to write a snapshot unit test to test a complex object. However, *Newtonsoft.Json JObject* properties are serialized into an empty array.

Verify version is 19.6.0.

How to make Verify to serialize JObject properly?

Code to validate:

- in the production project

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> ReturnStubResult()
    {
        return Ok( 
        new {
            Property1 = "value1",
            Property2 = 5,
            Property3 = new JObject()
            {
                ["ChildProperty1"] = "child value 1",
                ["ChildProperty2"] = 2
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- in the unit test project (reference Verify.Xunit library)

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestSnapshotSerialization()
{
    var controller = new TestController();

    var actionResult = await controller.ReturnStubResult();

    var okObjectResult = actionResult.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>().Which;

    await Verifier.Verify(okObjectResult.Value);
}
```

```
returned JSON:

{
  Property1: value1,
  Property2: 5,
  Property3: {
    ChildProperty1: [],
    ChildProperty2: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The team [switched](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/blob/main/docs/upgrade17-18.md#move-to-argon) to [Argon](https://github.com/SimonCropp/Argon) starting with version 18. This is their version of a hard fork of Newtonsoft.Json which they needed to add custom serialization. To fix the problem now we need to reference a hard fork of [Verify.Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify.NewtonsoftJson).

Then we would need to add a configuration line

```
[ModuleInitializer]
public static void Init() => VerifyNewtonsoftJson.Enable();
```

The reason behind the serialization problem seems to be that the hard copy of Newtonsoft.Json does not treat *Newtonsoft.Json Jobject* and *Argon JObect* to be the same type.

There is a neat [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995986/nested-jobjects-getting-serialized-as-empty-arrays) on a similar problem where an example of custom serializer was written to overcome it.