# What is going on with the parser of Json.NET (Newtonsoft) with timestamp strings?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string someJsonString = "{\"time\": \"2021-02-24T13:15:43Z\"}";
    JObject someJsonObject = JObject.Parse(someJsonString);          
    string time = someJsonObject.GetValue("time").Value<string>();
    Console.WriteLine(time);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[Using *Newtonsoft.Json* version *12.0.3*]

Why is the printed result is **02/24/2021 13:15:43** when it should be ***2021-02-24T13:15:43Z***, I just need the value as a string ... what is going on?

Comment: See https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1241

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [JToken: Get raw/original JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35138346/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON.Net will automatically parse a date formatted string into a `DateTime` object. If you want to prevent this, you either need to use a concrete class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise like this:

```
var f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(someJsonString);
```

Or if you really need a `JObject`, you can use a proper `JsonReader` object so you can configure how the parsing works, for example:

```
using var stringReader = new StringReader(someJsonString);
using var reader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader);
reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
JObject someJsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
```