# Json.net Parse function deserialize Json String remove timestamp trailing zero

Tags: c#, json.net, timestamp, zero, trailing

When calling json.net Parse method to deserialize json array string:
Either:

```
JArray.Parse(jsonArrayString)
```

Or

```
JObject.Parse(jsonArrayString with root node)
```

It always remove the trailing zero in timestamp milliseconds, e.g.

data: `"TimeStamp": "2019-10-01T11:36:43.840-04:00"`,
After deserilization: `"TimeStamp": "2019-10-01T11:36:43.84-04:00"`,

Found a bug before with json.net on remove trailing zero from decimals:https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1367
And updated newtonsoft.json from 10.0.1 to latest 12.0.2, but no luck with timestamp

jsonArrayString example:

```
[{"HistoryId": 430,"TimeStamp": "2019-10-01T11:36:43.840-04:00"}]
```

Then invoke with above value:

```
JArray.Parse(jsonArrayString)
```

Comment: `DateTime` has no precision data inside, so you will need to disable `DateTime` recognition.  To do that see [Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856835/3744182).

Comment: Great. The suggested solution works for JObject. Wonder is there a solution for JArray.Parse?

Comment: Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonArrayString, settings)`

Comment: Or `var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonArrayString)) { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None }; var array = JArray.Load(reader);`