# Apply IsoDateTimeConverter to Incoming Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I created a Web API in .Net, I added the global settings below:

```
 var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
 jsonSettings .Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ" });
```

Im always getting the date format  `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` but now I wish to change my setting to only convert on incoming not outgoing. e.g incoming `2022-08-22T13:42:27.407Z` and outgoing `2022-08-22 13:42:27`, I moved the setting to an `ActionFilterAttribute` OnActionExecuting, but doesnt work right. the date is already converted (ISO String setting 2 hours diff) when it reaches the OnActionExecuting function.

Is possible to change format for outgoing date format?

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_converters_isodatetimeconverter.htm) so it overrides [`CanRead`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanRead.htm) to return `false`.  Once done, the new converter will apply only for writing, and default serialization will be used for reading.

First, create the following converter:

```
public class WriteOnlyIsoDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => false;
}
```

And now the following unit test will pass:

```
var json = @"""2022-08-22T13:42:27.407Z""";

var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new WriteOnlyIsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" });

var dateTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(json, jsonSettings);

var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dateTime, jsonSettings);

Assert.AreEqual(@"""2022-08-22 13:42:27""", json2);
```

Notes:

- `2022-08-22T13:42:27.407Z` is already in the default serialization format used by Json.NET for `DateTime` objects, but if you need to change the default you can set [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatString.htm) or [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateTimeZoneHandling.htm).  The converter will be used for writing, and the (modified) defaults will be used for reading.
- If you want a converter to convert apply only when reading, override [`CanWrite`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanWrite.htm) instead.
- If you do want your custom `DateTime` converter to handle reading as well as writing, you may need to set [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm) to prevent `JsonTextReader` from automatically recognizing and parsing it before the `ReadJson()` method of your converter is called.  For details see *[Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11856694/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eRX03Q).